# Are meteors really missiles thrown at jinns by angels?

Tags: quran, jinn, malaikah

In [Surah Mulk, verse 5](https://quran.com/67/5), Allah says:

> وَلَقَدْ زَيَّنَّا السَّمَاءَ الدُّنْيَا بِمَصَابِيحَ وَجَعَلْنَاهَا
>   رُجُومًا لِلشَّيَاطِينِ ۖ وَأَعْتَدْنَا لَهُمْ عَذَابَ السَّعِيرِ
>
> And We have certainly beautified the nearest heaven with stars and
>   **have made [from] them what is thrown at the devils** and have prepared
>   for them the punishment of the Blaze.

How do we understand the highlighted phrase? **Does it refer to meteorites falling to  earth?** If yes, since they also fall on other planets, what do we make of their purpose?

According to science, [meteoroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid) come from [asteroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid) *(between Mars & Jupiter)* & comets *(from [Oort Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud))*. ***Is this in conflict with the above verse?***

**Note:**
To understand difference between meteoroids, meteors and meteorite please click [here](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-a-meteoroid-a-meteor-and-a-meteorite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a tafsir of the ayah:

> This does not mean that the stars themselves are pelted at the Satans, nor that the meteorites shoot out only to drive away the Satans, but it means that the countless meteorites which originate from the stars and wander in space at tremendous speeds and which also fall to the earth in a continuous shower prevent the Satans of the earth from ascending to the heavens. Even if they try to ascend heavenward these meteorites drive them away. ([Tafsir Maudodi](http://www.englishtafsir.com/Quran/67/index.html#sdfootnote9sym))

As you can see, what science says doesn't really contradict anything. All science says is that meteors and comets were formed from stars millions of years ago, and they orbit the solar system and are prevalent in the galaxy. The Quran does not say which type of meteor or comet. And it does not matter. What is being said is that the whole system of meteors and comets constantly orbitting the sun and falling to Earth is what prevents Satans from ascending the sky too high.

Answer (score -1):

This verse conflicts with reality at a deeper level than is explained away by the previous answer. Meteorites are made of normal matter traveling at non-relativistic speeds. If they can shoot down devils, it would mean that these unseen beings are made of normal matter and should be observable with current technology.

Also, this verse implies that the "nearest heaven" which is being guarded against devils can be reached at non-relativistic speeds from Earth. Light takes 4 years to travel to Earth from the nearest star to our solar system. This verse reveals an ignorance of the magnitude of our observable universe.

The obvious explanation is that this verse represents superstitions and the lack of understanding of cosmology at the time the Quran was authored.

Comment: From my limited understanding of Islam, Jinns and Angels are meta physical creatures that can travel faster than the speed of light. This is also illustrated in the ayah of Surah Naml where the throne was brought from Yemen to Jerusalem in blink of an eye while other Hadiths describe how angels travel between the heavens at Fajr & Asr times carrying our records.

Answer (score -3):

If an unseen thing made of a normal thing, it can be observed with current technology? Can current technology observe oxygen's physical appearance? how does it look like? If cannot, how can u said oxygen exist? do they really saw O2?

Comment: As long as you play nice, promise I won't let you die, but you will go unconscious. We just need your head in an air tight box and suck all the air out. You have admitted that you acknowledge a physical thing that you breathe and that if it's taken away you'll die. That hypothesis can be tested on anyone with same result. To prove it is Oxygen,a good method of testing for oxygen is to take a glowing splint and place it in a sample of gas, if it re-ignites the gas is oxygen

We “can't see” O2 isnt fair, we can't see anything really, we receive light particles and our brain creates an image,