# Hadith about stars and shooting stars

Tags: quran, hadith

**MY QUESTION:**
The hadith below tells us the prophet saw a shooting star, aka a meteor, and said this was a weapon used by angels against devils. The Quran verses say the stars are meant to be used as protection against devils.
Does this mean Prophet Muhammad thought shooting stars aka meteors were actual stars being thrown at devils? Because the prophet specifically talked about the meteor in regards to this, not anything else.
Meteors do look like bright flames in the sky as the quran describes.
Which wouldn't really make much sense, considering how vast space is...a 'shooting star' can be easily avoided...common sense would tell us this..

The quran however tells us that the stars themselves are the cause of these 'flames' being used to hit devils.  Also if the stars are being used, then that means the Jinns are traveling light years away from earth, because stars are so far apart, how would the other stars be of use as the quran describes.

Which means either:

1.) Prophet Muhammad knew the difference between a meteor and a star and really believed a meteor is so unavoidable to be hit by, so angels really used them to hit devils

2.) Perhaps the prophet got confused and thought a meteor 'shooting star' is an actual star...

3.) The hadith is fabricated...or mistranslated..

**Hadith:**

"We were with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), while he was sitting with a group of his Companions, ***when they saw a glowing shooting star***. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'When you saw the likes of this during Jahiliyyah, what would you say about it?' They said: 'We would say that a great man died, or that a great man has been born.' The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'It is not shot due to the death of anyone, nor his coming into life. Rather when our Lord [Blessed is His Name and Most High] decrees a matter, He is glorified by the bearers of the Throne. Then He is glorified by the inhabitants who are below them, then those below them, until such glorification reaches this Heaven. Then the inhabitants of the sixth Heaven ask the inhabitants of the seventh Heaven: "What did your Lord say?" He said: 'So they inform them; then the inhabitants of each Heaven seek the information, until the news is conveyed to the inhabitants of the Heavens of the earth. The Shayatin try to overhear so they are shot at, so they cast it down to their friends. Whatever they came with is true, as it is, but they distort it and add to it.'"

**Quran verses:**

72:8

> And we have sought [to reach] the heaven but found it filled with
> powerful guards and burning flames

72:9

> 'We used, indeed, to sit there in (hidden) stations, to (steal) a
> hearing; but any who listen now will find a flaming fire watching him
> in ambush.

37: 6-10

> Indeed, We have adorned the nearest heaven with an adornment of stars.
> And as protection against every rebellious devil. [So] they may not
> listen to the exalted assembly [of angels] and are pelted from every
> side. Repelled; and for them is a constant punishment, Except one who
> snatches [some words] by theft, but they are pursued by a burning
> flame, piercing [in brightness].

source:

https://sunnah.com/urn/642560 (they see a shooting star)

https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/introduction/194

**additional thoughts:**

**Edit start:**

So I just saw this post, which says both, shooting stars, and stars themselves prevent devils from ascending:
[Are meteors really missiles thrown at jinns by angels?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47074/are-meteors-really-missiles-thrown-at-jinns-by-angels?rq=1)

It's just strange, considering stars and meteors already existed, that the prophethood is what initiated the new method of 'shooting stars' because before that, the devils had no problem listening according to this hadith:
https://sunnah.com/urn/680340

**Edit end**

Comment: Your edit completely changes the point of the question. Please make one consistent question

Comment: ok updated, put it at the bottom as additional thoughts.

Comment: You have already linked to an answer that answer your primary question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean Prophet Muhammad thought shooting stars aka meteors were actual stars being thrown at devils?

It does not mean he thought they were "actual stars."

> Which wouldn't really make much sense, considering how vast space is...a 'shooting star' can be easily avoided...common sense would tell us this..

We don't know how the Jinn work and how they interact with stars or shooting stars. It is not possible for us to opine about it.

See here: [Are meteors really missiles thrown at jinns by angels?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47074/are-meteors-really-missiles-thrown-at-jinns-by-angels?rq=1)

> It's just strange, considering stars and meteors already existed, that the prophethood is what initiated the new method of 'shooting stars' because before that, the devils had no problem listening according to this hadith

The devils always had missiles thrown at them. However, when the revelation of the Quran was occurring and when Islam was revealed, this intensified and that is what the hadith is mentioning. Allah knows best how it was intensified.

Allah mentions the Jinn saying at the time of the Prophet:

> And we have sought [to reach] the heaven but found it filled with powerful guards and burning flames.  (72:8)

And this is the exact Surah that hadith is a tafsir of.

Comment: Yeah I guess 'masabeeh' isn't limited to stars, it could be other bright objects like comets/meteors burning. And yeah that interpretation of the hadith that it 'intensified' would resolve that possible contradiction. OK thanks! Hope others benefit from this!